# Pipfile Hash Creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, dependencies, pipenv

I am having issues with Pipenv. I run `pipenv install --dev` in order to install some dependencies from a Pipfile within my project. Upon running this command, Pipenv generates an MD5 hash for a certain dependency. The error is saying that MD5 is not supported yet still generates it. I have not set any configurations on my local machine or in any configuration file. I cannot seem to pinpoint this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

`[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: pip: error: Allowed hash algorithms for --hash are sha256, sha384, sha512.`

Pipfile.lock

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "7e0f1d75f7df19f9500f55bd2f1da163cb4a8c7f485aab61c521d70e3865a507"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.6"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "certain-dependency": {
            "hashes": [
                "md5:8faf2e4ff85c34b5d0c000c017f81f52",
                "md5:1508a7f05b17d292f7890b8c58a451cf",
   ],
            "version": "==11.10.20"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] with your Pipfile (at least with that "certain dependency") and specify the pipenv version.

Comment: @GinoMempin I have edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [clearing your pipenv cache](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose.html#your-dependencies-could-not-be-resolved):

> Make sure your dependencies actually do resolve. If you’re confident they are, you may need to clear your resolver cache. Run the following command:
>
> ```
> pipenv lock --clear
> ```
>
> and try again.
>
> If this does not work, try manually deleting the whole cache directory. It is usually one of the following locations:
>
> - `~/Library/Caches/pipenv` (macOS)
> - `%LOCALAPPDATA%\pipenv\pipenv\Cache` (Windows)
> - `~/.cache/pipenv` (other operating systems)

While the current release of pipenv only accepts sha256 hashes, it loads package URLs from a cache and writes those cached URLs' hashes to `Pipfile.lock`. If those cached hashes are md5 hashes from previously-installed packages, pipenv uses those values as-is [without verifying](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/e4bce0018e4364ff63447a7bab79826d1d33fc9e/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py#L88) that they are sha256/`FAVORITE_HASH`.

Clearing the cache and re-locking will cause pipenv to cache miss and re-fetch package URLs which end in sha256 hashes, and write them to `Pipfile.lock` as you'd hope, and prevent you from running into the issue again.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error with the most recent pipenv release (2020.11.4), it seems that a fix is already set for the next release (see https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/4519). But in the meantime what worked for me is just to rollback to the older version of pipenv (2020.8.13).

Comment: What's wild is that pipenv 2020.11.15 is adding md5 hashes to the lockfile, then erroring about them being there.

Comment: I just tried with an install from the master version of pipenv and the PR https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/4519 fixes this behavior is working well so the next release should work again. (You need to clear your cache in deed)